# iPhone, NSURLConnection > didReceiveData:(NSData *)data, How to check result data

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I use url connection (http).

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

        NSString *filePath; /* .../link.plist */
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
```

After connection, I check result file (link.plist)

```
    - (void)checkLinkResult {

        NSString *filePath; //link.plist
        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    }
```

It works fine.

But I want to check Result String, directly, without making file.

"NSData -> file -> NSString" (now) ====> "NSData -> NSString" (i want)

Help me plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's dependent your data.

If your data is Image

```
UIIMage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:Receivedata
```

If data is string

```
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initwithData:Receivedata encoding:nil]
```

Comment: Thanks! I did try NSUTF8StringEncoding. But it retun incorrect string. What means "endcoding: nil"?

Comment: If your character is UTF, you should use NSUTFStringEncoding

Comment: you put my code in: - **(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data** method?

Answer (score 0):

In didReceiveData write to an NSMutableData object, then in checkLinkResult create a string from the NSMUtableData using the appropriate encoding.

It's actually how it's done in the apple NSConnection tutorial.

Comment: How to know " the appropriate encoding."?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

1. Declare a file scope NSMutableData instance.
2. in your connection:DidRecieveData: callback append "data" to the previously created NSMutableData instance.
3. In connectionDidFinishLoading: callback use initWithData:encoding: of NSString and pass the NSMutableData instance and NSUTF8StringEncoding as parameters.